# How to check http status in a rxjs/expand inside a Angular resolver?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to check the status code on a GET request. If that GET request has a status of 204, then I need to call another api. This is in a resolver which is being used as a data guard in the Angular router.

How can I check the status code? I read where I am supposed to use expand for this kind of logic but I am stuck where I do not know how to get the status code. And since this is a resolver called by the router, I am not using subscribe.

```js
      const obs = this.http.get(url);
  
      return obs.pipe(
        expand((data: any) => {                               
         console.log(data);                                   
         return from(data);                                   
       }),
      );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the status code by passing the configuration `{observe: 'response'}` to the `this.http.get` function.

I don't think you need or have to use expand here. I would write it similar to the following:

```
return this.http.get(url, {observe: 'response'}).pipe(switchMap((response) => {
      if (response.status === 204) {
        // return new endpoint call
        return this.http.get(otherUrl)
      } else {
        // return original data
        return response.body;
      }
    }))
```